# Accepted threshold to use for accepting results after empirically estimating a FDR from repeated randomization of the original data set?

Tags: false-discovery-rate, threshold

### Question:

Is there a "rule of thumb" for choosing a False Discovery Rate threshold for accepting results when empirically estimating an FDR from repeated randomization of the original data set to abolish the "real" relationships?

### Example:

Lets say that I have three linked data sets:

`A` = $\{A_0 \dots A_n\}$

`B` = $\{B_0 \dots B_n\}$

`C` = $\{C_0 \dots C_n\}$

The sets are linked in that comparisons are only valid between members of:

`comparison_sets_real` = $\{A_i, B_i, C_i\}$

I have a distribution (`REAL`) of results generated using `comparison_sets_real`.

I then shuffle the order of sets `A`, `B`, and `C` such that 
`comparison_sets_null` = $\{A_r, B_r, C_r\}$ represent the same data set but with the real relationships abolished.

A large number of randomized distributions are generated (~1000) and a median distribution (`NULL`) is derived from the set of randomized distributions.

From comparing the `REAL` and `NULL` distributions using a [reversed cumulative histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzQMg.png) we can generate a [progressively more stringent FDR threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DcDY.png) [1].

**Is there a standard guideline similar to the $\alpha$ of p-values?**

#### Footnotes:

1. In the provided images, the randomization replication is set at 15 to reduce calculation times. Actual results would be generated with ~1000 replications.